# Echo PHP variable based on HTML tag value

Tags: php, html, tags, ternary

I need a way to echo out my `$title` variable into a HTML tag value but I need to check to make sure it's not blank first.

```
<input name="title-field" id="title-field" type="text" value="<?php echo ($title != '') ? $title: ''; ?>" />
```

How can i do this?

Comment: if is blank what you want to show?

Comment: the content of what would be in the title variable.

Comment: You get an warning currently?

Comment: What does this give you. Show us the output

Comment: I'm confused by this question, if its actually blank it doesn't matter if you echo it out or not.  Are you trying to check to see if there are spaces or returns in the variable? Can you give us more information.

Comment: It would be good to define ‘blank’. In the PHP `0 == ''` is `true`.

Comment: I'm attempting to use the wordpress function delete_option() to delete some entries from the WP db options table. Whenever i do so, the data that was pre-populated into the form fields disappears and causes the php echos inside of the html values to fail and I get errors.

Answer (score 0):

To make it more readable you don't need an else. Just check if there is a title to display:

```
<input name="title-field" id="title-field" type="text" value="<?php if($title != ''){echo $title;} ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using this for checking if your variable is empty or has only whitespace:

```
$str = '      ';
if (ctype_space($str)) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine

```
  <?php 

        $title = "teste here";
        ?>
        <input name="title-field" id="title-field" type="text" value="<?php if(!empty($title)){echo $title; }?" />
```

so to make sure it's not empty you do `if(!empty($var)){echo $var;}`

Comment: <?php if(!empty($tittle){echo $title; } if not empty it will echo

Answer (score 0):

you can check and echo the html

```
<?php 
     if ($title != '') {
        echo '<input name="title-field" id="title-field" type="text" value="'. $title .'">';
      } else {

        echo '<input name="title-field" id="title-field" type="text" >';

      }
?>
```